# comparing the output of stat command with integer variable in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, split

I am trying to compare the *stat* output with the integer. I am not getting the expected output out of it.

```
XX_CONFIG_LOCATION=/tmp/config.txt
MAXIMUM_FILE_SIZE=123000
FILESIZE= stat --printf=%s $XX_CONFIG_LOCATION

if [[ "$FILESIZE" -gt "$MAXIMUM_FILE_SIZE" ]]
then
   echo "file size is greater"
else
   echo "file size is lesser"
fi
```

Here output of *split* command 123784(filesize) but the maximum filesize is 123000. Here expected output is "file is greater " but every time i am getting file size is lesser. What is the problem with the code?

Answer (score 3):

You need command substitution to save the STDOUT (or STDERR) of a command in a variable:

```
FILESIZE=$(stat --printf='%s\n' "$XX_CONFIG_LOCATION")
```

As it currently stands the variable `FILESIZE` is set to null and while doing arithmetic comparison the `bash` keyword `[[` giving the right output:

```
$ foo=                            
$ [[ $foo -gt 4 ]] && echo OK || echo Not OK
Not OK
```

Also note that, `bash` (and other shells) does not allow allow space(s) around `=` in variable declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing new , but here is the reason for your failure.  Did you notices where is the file attribute (75 in this case) is squeezed in ?

## Case-I:

```
ola:ola~/.scratch$ stat --printf=%s sample.txt
**75ola**@ola:~/.scratch$
```

## Case-II:

```
ola:ola~/.scratch$ stat --printf='%s\n' sample.txt
75
ola@ola:~/.scratch$
```